# Extract only time (HH:MM) from datetime field - Odoo 10

Tags: python, datetime, odoo-10

I'a m trying  to  extract  only time (Hour:Minute) from datetime field

Example:

```
today_with_hour = fields.Datetime(
    string=u'hora',
    default=fields.Datetime.now,
)
```

I would like to know how get  only hour from **today_with_hour** in format

**17:10:20**

Answer (score 0):

This is one way to extract:

```
from datetime import datetime

now  = datetime.now()
print(str(now.hour)+':'+str(now.minute)+':'+str(now.second))
```

Comment: Hello,@arajshee please  accept my apologies, I have modified the question

Answer (score 0):

This may be better way to do it

You can use ***strftime***

Example:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

In your case you can follow like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('20/06/2019 17:28:52', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S").time()
```

**Output will be:
17:28:52**

Comment: Hello,@sfx please   accept my apologies, I have modified the question

Answer (score 0):

Better way to do is by using strftime().

```
dt = datetime.strptime('20/06/2019 17:28:52', "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
dt.strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

output:

```
17:28:52
```

To get the current time from the datetime.now()

```
datetime.datetime.now().time().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
```

O/P:

```
'11:16:17'
```

if you want to get the time with milliseconds also, use isoformat()

```
datetime.datetime.now().time().isoformat()
```

O/P:

```
'11:20:34.978272'
```

Comment: Hello @Naresh, please  accept my apologies, I have modified the question

Comment: Hi @ayar, I have added the answer to get the time from datetime.now(). Is this what you are expected output?